# WP7 Isolated Storage Text Document Read Line

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, storage

Is there a way using Isolated storage ie a Text document, to grab the text on a certain line.
I would like to save variables to a text document on my settings page of my app. Then go back to the main page and read the variable saved on line 3. I already know how to save them. just not read certain lines.

Also is the text document created by my app going to still be there if i close and reopen the app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
using( TextReader reader = new StreamReader( 
         new IsolatedStorageFileStream( "myFile.txt", System.IO.FileMode.Open, 
           IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication() ) ) {

    string line = reader.ReadLine(); // first line, discard
    line = reader.ReadLine();        // second line, discard
    line = reader.ReadLine();        // third line, read the variable value
}
```

However, you might be better off using the [`IsolatedStorageSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings%28VS.95%29.aspx) class to store settings (the link contains example usage). Another option is to put all your settings into a serializable class and use an [`XmlSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) to save / read the settings. Both these approaches would not require parsing the file manually.

Comment: Also is the document saved when i close the app and reopen it? Thanks

Comment: @Al3xhamilton If you use `IsolatedStorageSettings` the framework automatically saves it for you on app exit. With your approach and `XmlSerializer` you need to manually save changes.